# QStateMachine how it works

Tags: c++, qt, qstatemachine

I've created 4 different QState and i want to hide one object in evry state transition.

This is the code:

```
QStateMachine partita;

QState *inizio_mano = new QState();
QState *aspetto_G1_primo = new QState();
QState *aspetto_G1_secondo = new QState();
QFinalState *fine_mano = new QFinalState();

partita.setInitialState(inizio_mano);

inizio_mano -> addTransition(this,presa==true,aspetto_G1_primo);
inizio_mano -> addTransition(this,presa==false,aspetto_G1_secondo);
aspetto_G1_primo -> addTransition(this,stato==true,fine_mano);
aspetto_G1_secondo -> addTransition(this,stato==true,fine_mano);
```

`presa` and `stato` are two `bool` I change in the next step of program.

Now I have a `QGraphicsScene` and in the scene I've added in it some `QGraphicsPixmapItem`.

For example I want to update the scene hiding an item:

```
if(presa==true) {object1->hide();}
```

I understand I have to change the QState (in this case from `inizio_mano` to `aspetto_G1_primo`), and I've done it adding a transition.

But how I can hide that Item ?

How can I connect the QState `aspetto_G1_primo` with `object1 -> hide();`

I hope I explained correctly.

My main problem is: how do I assign to each QState a different configuration of the scene ?

Comment: The `addTransition` statements you wrote are invalid. Transitions can be triggered *only* by signal emission or upon receiving an event. Please fix your code to make it compile first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all the properties of a `QWidget` here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#properties

Each child class also have their own additional properties, which are in the doc.

So you can do :

```
aspetto_G1_primo->assignProperty(object1, "visible", false);
```

Then when entering that state the property "visible" of `object1` will be set to `false`.

You can also do the same to edit *any* other property depending on the state, such as the geometry, the stylesheet, or the text of labels...